# Debug innards of IEnumerable<T>.Join()

Tags: linq, join, extension-methods, inner-join

How can I debug the innards of the Join() extension method?

I am NOT asking how to debug/see things in between chained method calls.  NOT tring to look between the dots in this example: `myThings.Where().Join();`

Instead, I want to see the intermediate values or the internal inner/outer sequences that the Join() method uses to work its mojo.  I have: `myThings.Join( a bunch of lambdas );` My keySelectors seem be to returning the correct data.  But my resultSelector is never getting called so I want to see the sequences themselves and debug.

I feel like someone will recommend resharper (I don't have $150 to shell out, so please only offer free alternatives).

Please answer the question: "How can I debug the innards of Join()?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a conceptual look at how `Join` is implemented have a look at Jon Skeet's re-implementation as part of EduLinq: ["Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 19 - Join"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-19-join.aspx). I would start here because it will probably give you much more insight into what is going on than just starring at the generated code.

If you still want to decompile the generated code using a free tool there is e.g. [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) available for free.

Comment: +1 and thank you for both links.  I used the decompiler and was able to look under the covers but I wound up giving up.  In the end I copied Jon Skeet's quick and dirty implementation and stepped through his Join() method and found the bug.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think in VS there is an debug option to let you debug .net source code. It should be in menu Debug->Options->General

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflector .NET  7 and newer you're able to debug framework types. You're basically debugging the decompiled versions of the framework. It's a great way to learn.

Comment: .NET Reflector is a tool from Red-gate (see: http://www.reflector.net/) there is a free trial that supports debugging of external assemblies, including the framework sources.

Comment: v7 makes more sense now.  Thanks for the tip.  I am relunctant to install yet another add-in only to have the trial expire...  Thanks for the reference.